# Dimanic Model in Java

Tags: java, android, model

I'm making a contacts app, this is my model.

```
 public class Contact {
        private RelationShip relationShip;

        public static class RelationShip {
           private Friend   friend;
           private Enemie   enemie;
           private Family   family;

           private class Family {
               private Brother brother;
               private Sister sister;
           }

        }
    }
```

I want to create it you can do it the way suiguiente.

```
RelationShip realation = new RelationShip(RelationShip.Friend);

Contact contact = new Contact(realation);
```

I want to establish the kind of relationship in a variable. Really do not know how to ask the question. an example would be something like this:

`layout.setOrientation (LinearLayout.VERTICAL)`;

Comment: what is "suiguiente" ? your question is unclear but I have the feeling that [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Excellent thanks. If that was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearLayout.VERTICAL` is a **constant** or an **enumerate**. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#VERTICAL) for example.

To achieve the same behavior in your code set those values as constants (usually int).

```
public static class RelationShip {
    public static final int FRIEND = 0;
    public static final int ENEMIE = 1;
    public static final int FAMILY = 2;

    ...

    }

public class Contact {
    private int relationshipType;

    ...

    public void setRelationShipType(int relationShip) {

    }

    public boolean areWeFriends() {
        if (relationshipType==Relationship.FRIEND)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can then set the relationship `setRelationShipType(Relationship.FRIEND)`. Or check if the relationship of `Contact HerryPotter` is a friend with `HarryPotter.areWeFriends()`

**EDIT:**

Actually the correct way is indeed the one suggested by alfasin: using enumerates.

```
public enum RelationShip {
    FRIEND, ENEMIE, FAMILY
    }

public class Contact {
    private RelationShip relationshipType;

    public void setRelationShipType(RelationShip relationShip) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean areWeFriends() {
        if (relationshipType==Relationship.FRIEND)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `enum` was introduced in Java 5, it is no longer recommended to use groups of constants like you do in your example! See item 30 here: http://mishadoff.com/blog/effective-java/

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited the solution to contemplate the use of enumerates as it should on the first place.

Comment: Looks much better, thanks for taking the time to update the answer!